# В каком порядке удаляется ответ?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, удаление-ответов

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/176469

Почему участники в очереди проверок и в списке удаливших ответ идут в разном порядке?

[image: порядок проверки]

[image: порядок удаления]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В шапке указано по обратной хронологии (видно по дате). Под сообщением участники перечислены по мере увеличения id. Наверное, так было проще. Хотя внизу тоже бы стоило указать в хронологическом порядке.

Comment: Про обратную-то ясно, а вот про id бы даже не подумал)

Comment: @Qwertiy я здесь тоже немного удивился разнице в id между первыми двумя участниками при одинаковом сроке в статусе зарегистрированного.

Comment: С переездом с хэшкода на so не связано? Я после регистрировался и довольно близок к твоему.

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю. Меня на ХК не было.

Comment: Так меня - тоже. А его?

Comment: @Qwertiy моя не знать. Надо CM опросить.

Comment: Кого? А Darth'а в чате нет спросить :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Николаса нашего, кого ж еще.